# Single error correcting binary code of length $16$ and size $2^{12}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

Consider there is a 12 bit data, and we want to add 4 check bits, such that 1-bit errors can be detected and corrected.

How can this be done ?

Consider the data as :

b15 b14 b13 b12
b11 b10 b09 b08
b07 b06 b05 b04

b03 b02 b01 b00 <- check bits

I tried using parity counting, but that only detects error.

b03 = b15 xor b14 xor b13 xor b12 ; this doesn't allow correction of errors.

Can anyone suggest a way ?

Thanks.

Comment: `I tried using parity counting, but that only detects error.` Is that an issue?

Comment: @GitGud I need to correct the error as well. Changing 1000 to 1001 changes parity from odd to even, but doesn't tell which bit is changed.

Comment: I realise now what you're doing wrong. In the matrix you provided, are the check bits only the last line?

Comment: @GitGud Yes. What have I done wrong ?

Comment: Adding a column parity check (in addition to the line parity check) should fix it. That way whenever you have an error, the parity check will fail on a line and on a column, that's where your error will be.

Comment: @GitGud I can only use 4 check bits for 12 bit of data. Aren't you suggesting 8 check bits for the 12 bit data ?

Comment: I'm suggesting that, yes. Sorry, I forgot you can only add 4 check bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cannot be done. You want to have a code of length 16 that has $2^{12}$ codewords. To each codeword $x$ we associate the ball of radius one $B(x)$ that consists of the word $x$ itself, and the sixteen words that differ from $x$ in a single position. Thus $|B(x)|=17.$ For the error correction to work out as promised, the balls $B(x)$ and $B(x')$ must not overlap, when $x\neq x'$. There are $2^{12}$ choices for $x$, so between them the balls $B(x)$ contain $17\cdot2^{12}$ bit vectors. But there are only $2^{16}$ vectors of length 16 total.

Comment: Another argument proving the impossibility is the following. You have 4 check bits, so the check sequence has $2^4=16$ possibilities. For you to succeed you need $17$ possibilities: one telling that no errors occured, 16 to tell where the error is (the error can be in any sixteen possitions). Thus you must be able to distinguish between seventeen cases, and that is asking too much.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for a binary code of length $16$, size $2^{12}$ and minimum Hamming distance at least $3$. Unfortunately, such a code does not exist.